# Julia: Override method to add functionality

Tags: julia, overriding

I would like to *extend* an abstract type's method in a concrete type.
I can do it with a new method but this introduces more complexity:

```
abstract type AbstractTask end
function complete(task::AbstractTask)
    complete_concrete_task(task)
    println("Done!")
end

struct Task <: AbstractTask
    name::String
end
complete_concrete_task(task::Task) = println(task.name)
```

```
coding = Task("coding")
complete(coding)
```

In Python, I would use the `super` operator. Is there an equivalent in Julia?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is wrong with this way of doing it? It seems like the right approach. Using `invoke`/`super` is not very idiomatic afaict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that using dispatch the way you did introduces much less *cognitive* complexity than a call to `super`.  But you can use [`invoke`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.invoke) select methods of supertypes:

```
julia> abstract type AbstractTask end

julia> function complete(task::AbstractTask)
           println("Done!")
       end
complete (generic function with 1 method)

julia> struct Task <: AbstractTask
           name::String
       end

julia> complete(task::Task) = (println(task.name); invoke(complete, Tuple{AbstractTask}, task))
complete (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> coding = Task("coding")
Task("coding")

julia> complete(coding)
coding
Done!
```

Of course this requires you not to forget to add it to every subtype method, which is the additional complexity I mean.

The good thing is that `invoke` with a constant type parameter will be compiled away (or so I have read), so there's not even overhead from dispatch.